# dealing with date field in sqlite for android application

Tags: android, sqlite

I have defined insert method for my table in android application as follow :

```
public long CreateBirthDay(long id,Date _date)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_ID, id);
    initialValues.put(KEY_Date, dateFormat.format(_date));

    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

But I dont know how to get date from cursor. I mean I cant complete the below code:

```
 bc.SetID(mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));

 bc.SetDate(?);
```

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bc.SetDate(dateFormat.parse(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_Date))));
```

Comment: What is dateFormat ? how is it initialized? I am a newbie to JAVA

Comment: SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); you are already done it

Answer (score 0):

insert datetime as numeric using following function.

long time=datetime.gettime();

agagnin use the Date date =new Date(cursor coloumn index) to get the date object.